# Dispatching update* calls into Shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I was implementing a Shiny module that allows users to update internal components from outside, as if it were a "common" Shiny control.
The idea was to imitate the Shiny mechanism (e.g. change a `textInput` through the function `updateTextInput`), by providing an updater function (`updateTextInModule`) that is aware of the internal structure but hides it to the user.

To do this, one needs to access to the fully qualified ID of the control: this includes the module ID, that I was not able to find anywhere (unless the user provides it in the call).

I managed to write this code that works perfectly:

```r
library(shiny)

# Module ------------------------------------------------------------------

# UI: a single textInput to be modified
module_ui <- function(id){
   ns <- NS(id)
   textInput(ns('txt_input'), label = 'Update me:', value = 'Original text')
}

module_server <- function(input, output, session){
   ns <- session$ns
}

# Updater function
#
# forwards the call to updateTextInput inside the module
updateTextInModule <- function(session, module_id, ...) {
   shiny::updateTextInput(session = session, inputId = NS(module_id, id = 'txt_input'), ...)
}

# Main app ----------------------------------------------------------------

# The module UI, and a button that updates it.
ui <- bootstrapPage(
   module_ui("module_id_ui_1"),

   actionButton('btn_update', 'Update the text!')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
   callModule(module_server, "module_id_ui_1")

   observeEvent(input$btn_update, {
      updateTextInModule(session, module_id = "module_id_ui_1", value = 'Updated!')
   })
}

# Runner ------------------------------------------------------------------

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(Of course this is an example, one should capture the dots `...` in `updateTextInModule` to restrict the interface.)

Questions:

1. Is it good practice to introduce such functions? The `NS` call sounds hackish, but it is what Shiny uses to create the ID.
2. Am I missing something? Can one do better?

Thanks!